# How to save and display uploaded image via tinymce editor in MOODLE 2.9

Tags: tinymce, moodle

Save and display `tinymce` content in **Moodle**.

I have a block that save question and answer in db.

I use `tinymce editor` for this, so that user can enter text and image.

My editor form is:

```
.....
$editoroptions = array('maxfiles' => EDITOR_UNLIMITED_FILES, 'noclean'=>true, 'context'=>$context);
        $mform->addElement('editor', 'title_editor', 'Questions', null, $editoroptions);
        $mform->addRule('title_editor', null, 'required', null, 'client');
        $mform->setType('title_editor', PARAM_RAW);
.....
```

I submit the form and save the data(text+image) from tinymce in db

```
......

if($data = $sample_form->get_data()) {
if ($draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('title_editor')) {
    $data->title_editor['text'] = file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $contextid, 'block_sample', questiontext, array('subdirs' => true, 'maxfiles' => 5),$data->title_editor['text']);
}

//insert to database
$inserRecord = new stdClass();
$inserRecord->suggestion     = $sgid;
$inserRecord->questiontext     = $data->title_editor['text'];
$inserRecord->answertext     = $data->answer['text'];
$insertRes = add_question_desc($inserRecord);
......
```

In db the data(here question and answer) saved. The question data is looks like:

```
<p>What color is this?</p>
<p><img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/sample_image.png" width="309" height="212" alt="green" /></p>
```

Is this complete to save the data?  Where did the uploaded file saved. How I retreive/display the uploaded file.

I use:

```
$qn = file_rewrite_pluginfile_urls($qnDetails[$qnid]->questiontext, "pluginfile.php", $context->id, "block_sample", 'questiontext', $qnid);
echo $qn;
```

The above code only display the text and image is not displaying.

[image]

I inspect the broken image field and it is:

```
<img src="http://localhost/moodle/pluginfile.php/24/block_sample/questiontext/12/mc4.png" width="309" height="212" alt="mc4.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate files in an editor you must use the following methods:

- Prior to displaying the form: `file_prepare_standard_editor()`
- When saving the form: `file_postupdate_standard_editor()`
- When displaying the content: `file_rewrite_pluginfile_urls()` followed by `format_text()`

You can find an example of this in `cohort/edit.php` and `cohort/index.php`.

Once that is done, you need to implement the function `_pluginfile` which Moodle core will call to get the file. The `_pluginfile` functions are required so that your plugin can check whether or not the user can access the file. You can find default implementations in `filelib.php file_pluginfile()` and in various `lib.php <component_name>_pluginfile()`.