# Images(uploaded via tinymce) is not displaying in Block in Moodle 2.9

Tags: tinymce, moodle

In **Moodle** `block` (example `block_sample`) the images uploaded via `tinymce` editor is not displaying.

I save the text (with image) in db as:

```
 $context = context_block::instance($instanceid);
if($data = $question_form->get_data()) {
 if ($draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('title')) {
    $data->title['text'] = file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $context->id 'block_sample', 'content', 0, array('subdirs' => true, 'maxfiles' => 5),$data->title['text']);

$inserRecord = new stdClass();
$inserRecord->blockid     = $cid;
$inserRecord->content     = $data->title['text'];
$insertRes = $DB->insert_record("sample_data", $inserRecord);
    }
}
```

Here `content` is the db field name where the question is saved.

And  the data is saved in db as

```
id       blockid        content
1         2             <p>Test</p><p><img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/flower_123.jpeg" width="200" height="200" /></p>
```

Now I need to display the data from db(for example first record):

```
$descDetails = $DB->get_records('sample_data', array('id'=>1));

    $qn = file_rewrite_pluginfile_urls($descDetails[1]->content, "pluginfile.php", $context->id, "block_sample", 'content', $descDetails[1]->id);
    $format = FORMAT_HTML;
        $filteropt = new stdClass;
        $filteropt->overflowdiv = true;
        $qn = format_text($qn, $format, $filteropt);
        echo $qn;
```

But the image is not displaying here. How can I fix this?
I inspect the element and I got:

```
<img src="http://localhost/moodle/pluginfile.php/122/block_sample/content/1/flower_123.jpeg" width="297" height="203" alt="d" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1476699462273_239">
```

Please help me..Is there any issue while taking the `context id` of **block** or there is another issue.

For `moodle module(activity)` I am successfully displayed the image for the same case. This is not working in the case of `moodle block`.

The only difference here, is taking the `context id` for `activity module` and `block`.

For `activity module` I take the `context id` as:

```
$context = context_module::instance($cm->id);
```

Conclusion: **For activity module the images (uploaded via tinymce editor) is displaying but for moodle block images is not displaying.**

How can I resolve this?

**EDIT**

`block_sample_pluginfile` function in `lib.php` (refer from `block_html_pluginfile` function )

```
function block_sample_pluginfile($course, $birecord_or_cm, $context, $filearea, $args, $forcedownload, array $options=array()) {
    global $DB, $CFG, $USER;

    if ($context->contextlevel != CONTEXT_BLOCK) {
        send_file_not_found();
    }

    // If block is in course context, then check if user has capability to access course.
    if ($context->get_course_context(false)) {
        require_course_login($course);
    } else if ($CFG->forcelogin) {
        require_login();
    } else {
        // Get parent context and see if user have proper permission.
        $parentcontext = $context->get_parent_context();
        if ($parentcontext->contextlevel === CONTEXT_COURSECAT) {
            // Check if category is visible and user can view this category.
            $category = $DB->get_record('course_categories', array('id' => $parentcontext->instanceid), '*', MUST_EXIST);
            if (!$category->visible) {
                require_capability('moodle/category:viewhiddencategories', $parentcontext);
            }
        } else if ($parentcontext->contextlevel === CONTEXT_USER && $parentcontext->instanceid != $USER->id) {
            // The block is in the context of a user, it is only visible to the user who it belongs to.
            send_file_not_found();
        }
        // At this point there is no way to check SYSTEM context, so ignoring it.
    }

    if ($filearea !== 'content') {
        send_file_not_found();
    }

    $fs = get_file_storage();

    $filename = array_pop($args);
    $filepath = $args ? '/'.implode('/', $args).'/' : '/';

    if (!$file = $fs->get_file($context->id, 'block_sample', $filearea, 0, $filepath, $filename) or $file->is_directory()) {
        send_file_not_found();
    }

    if ($parentcontext = context::instance_by_id($birecord_or_cm->parentcontextid, IGNORE_MISSING)) {
        if ($parentcontext->contextlevel == CONTEXT_USER) {
            // force download on all personal pages including /my/
            //because we do not have reliable way to find out from where this is used
            $forcedownload = true;
        }
    } else {
        // weird, there should be parent context, better force dowload then
        $forcedownload = true;
    }

    // NOTE: it woudl be nice to have file revisions here, for now rely on standard file lifetime,
    //       do not lower it because the files are dispalyed very often.
    \core\session\manager::write_close();
    send_stored_file($file, null, 0, $forcedownload, $options);
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the function `block_sample_pluginfile`? The latter is required when you are defining new file areas.

Comment: Actually, this is very similar to the question you asked here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40043249/867720, which I replied to. I updated my answer to add the `pluginfile` parts which I had forgotten.

Comment: @FMC, `block_sample_pluginfile` is there in `lib.php`

Comment: Did you review the answers to the your other questions, it may also be a context issue. Did you confirm that the function `block_sample_pluginfile` was called? Could we see its content?

Comment: I think I get the correct `context` of my block using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085222/what-is-the-correct-context-id-of-moodle-block/40110989#40110989. But still the problem exist image is not displaying.

Comment: I require `lib.php` and `filelib.php` in my view page and action page. `lib.php` contain the `block_sample_pluginfile` function.

Comment: Could you please share your `pluginfile` function?

Comment: @FMC, I added `pluginfile` function in question. Please take a look at the **EDIT** section.

Comment: `if ($filearea !== 'content') { send_file_not_found();}`, your filearea is `questiontext`. I suggest you review your `pluginfile` function.

Comment: Initially I put `questiontext` as `filearea`. Since it is not working I change it to `content` in all places. Sorry for the typo. I updated my question please check.

Comment: @FMC, is there any problem in `pluginfile` function or anywhere else?