# What is the correct context id of Moodle block

Tags: block, moodle

What is the correct `context id` of **Moodle block,** `block_html`.

**case1**

In `block_html.php` file

`$this->context->id` inside `get_content` function gives **122**

**case2**

I create a new page named `view.php`. Here I try

```
$instance = $DB->get_record('block_instances', array('id' => 57));
$blockname = 'html';
$block = block_instance($blockname, $instance);
echo $block->context->id;
```

and this gives **98**.

**case3**

```
$context = context_block::instance($cmid);

echo $context->id
```

gives **7**

What should I use as `context id` of `block_html`. I need the exact `context id`.

Note: For all blocks I am getting the issue described above. What is the wrong I used?

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 and 2** should be correct.

In `block::get_content()` you get the right context of the block using `$this->context`, for sure.

To manually get the context of a block you do `context_block::instance($instanceid)`. I suspect is that in your example you mistakenly used the wrong block instance ID. You can get the block instance ID from `get_content` using `$this->context->instanceid`.

Comment: using `$this->context->instanceid` I found `contex `of my `block`. Now the `case1` and `case2` gives same `context`. I think its the correct context of my block.

Comment: Could you validate the answer please?